# How to get value from dynamically created hidden field in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden

In my use case, I am trying to get value from dynamically generated hidden field in JQuery. When I click the button for that iteration I should get the value for the hidden field belongs to that iteration. But I am not able to get it. It is giving the value as 'undefined'

**HTML:**

```
<div class="comment-list-new" style= "max-height: 660px !important;overflow-y: scroll;">
    <h5>Discussion Board</h5>
    <ol>
        {{  if .ViewData.Questions }}
        {{ range .ViewData.Questions }}
            <li>
                <p id="question_id" class="question_id_val" hidden>{{.QuestionId}}</p>
                <div class="q-comment">
                    <div class="qanda questiondiv" id="questionarea" name="questionarea">
                        <div>
                            <div id="topic" class="upvote pull-left">
                                <a class="upvote"></a>
                                <span class="count">3</span>
                                <a class="downvote"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <div class="qanda-info">
                                    <h6><p id="quest_title">{{.QuestionTitle}}</p></h6>
                                </div>
                                <p id="quest_text">{{.QuestionText}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div >
                        <div class="qanda-info">
                        <div class="user-info">
                            <img src="/resources/img/team-small-2.png" />
                        </div>
                        <h6>{{.UserId}}</h6>
                        <span class="date alt-font sub">{{.DateCreated}}</span>
                        <a id="answertext" name ="answertext" type="submit" class="link-text answerbutton">Answer</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li><!--end of individual question-->
         {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
    </ol>
</div><!--end of comments list-->
```

**JS:**

```
$('.questiondiv').on('click', '.submitanswerbutton', function() {
    console.log("In submit button");
    var question_id = $(this).closest('.question_id_val').val();
    var answer_text = $('.answertext_val').val();
    console.log(question_id);
    console.log(answer_text);
    $.getJSON("/submitanswer?question_id="+question_id+"&answer="+answer_text, function(data) {
            console.log("answer Response"+data);
            newQuestion = "<li><div class='q-comment'><div class='qanda' id='questionarea' name='questionarea'><div><div id='topic' class='upvote pull-left'><a class='upvote'></a><span class='count'>0</span><a class='downvote'></a></div><div ><div class='qanda-info'><h6><p id='quest_title'>"+title+"</p></h6></div><p id='quest_text'>"+desc+"</p></div></div ><div class='qanda-info'><div class='user-info'><img src='/resources/img/team-small-2.png' /></div><h6>Chip Mayer</h6><span class='date alt-font sub'>September 17 2014</span><a id='answertext' name ='answertext' type='submit' class='link-text'>Answer</a></div></div></div></li>";
            $('ol').append(newQuestion);
    });
});
```

In the above code I am trying to get the value for the hidden field `question_id_val`.
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `closest()` to get a reference to the outer container (li) and then use `find()` method to get the hidden field.

```
 var question_id = $(this).closest('li').find('.question_id_val').val();
```

`val()` method works for usually input form fields(textbox,hidden fields etc..) .So you need to make sure your element is a valid form field in your page.

```
<input type="hidden" id="question_id" class="question_id_val" />
```

Or if you want to keep your p tag as it is, Use the `html()` or `text()` method to get the content of the p tag.

```
var question_id = $(this).closest('li').find('.question_id_val').text();
```

Remember, these method returns the text/html of all child content as well. So make sure to use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a css selector `id` or `class` I don't see problem why you can't do something like this:

```
var question_id = $('#question_id').text();
```

Or

```
var question_id = $('.question_id_val').text();
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

val() should be used primarily in select, textarea and input elements.

For getting the inner text use html() or text()

```
var question_id = $(this).closest('.question_id_val').html();
```

or

```
var question_id = $(this).closest('.question_id_val').text();
```